# Ultrasonic Sensor HC-SR04 + Arduino Calculation?

Tags: c++, c, arduino, sensors

I'm using this code :

```
int trigPin = 7;
int echoPin = 8;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(trigPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  int duration;
  int distance;
  digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(1000);
  digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);
  duration = pulseIn (echoPin,HIGH);
  distance = (duration/2)/29.1;
  Serial.print("distance = ");
  Serial.println (distance);
  delay(500);
}
```

I understand the concept that we send a pulse of 1000 µsec in this case and we wait for the reflected signal. But I don't understand how in this code, only the pulse width of the reflected signal is being used for the calculation.

I searched around and they say the reflected pulse width is proportional to the distance traveled. Can someone please explain how this happens (the physics behind it) and also where does the 29.1 comes from?

I read [this documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Y-yZnNhMYy7rwhAgyL_pfa39RsB-x2qR4vP8saG73rE/edit) but I still don't understand the pulse width concept.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it is measuring the width of the reflected pulse, and not simply the "width" of a single which changes state when the (comparatively short) reflected pulse arrives?

Comment: @chrisStatton On page 7 of the doc I attached it shows the pulse diagram and says "echo pulse width corresponds to distance"... and also the pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH) function gives the On time of the echo pulse. So thats the only thing I have inferred from it!

Comment: The pulse returned from the module is not the width of the ultrasonic pulse transmitted or detect though, it is fundamentally the time delay between the two.

Comment: oh I got it. So actually when the pulse is received, the echo pin generates a HIGH signal which has a pulse width equal to the time(in microseconds) it took for the ultrasonic pulse to hit the obstacle and bounce back... That's why we use the pulseIn function to find the pulse width because it is actually the time... thanks @ChrisStratton , you helped a lot ...

Comment: I think the pulse probably starts with or just after the sent pulse, and runs to an equal delay relative to the received pulse.  I supposed it is possible it is "recorded and played back" by charging and discharging a capacitor or something, but that seems more complicated than would at first glance seem necessary.  If you really want to know which, see if the delay from triggering the transmission to the start (not end) of the answer pulse is constant, or varies with distance.

Comment: yeah i think exactly the same as what you mentioned that it is sorta recorded and played back! but I guess they made the internal circuitry do all the magic and made it easier to deal with at the programmer end... My problem actually was that it seemed a little too simplistic to me and I started wondering what goes on inside... I guess its all in the internal mechanism..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Chris touched on in the comments, the input pin goes HIGH for the time between it being send and received. I'm not exactly sure if it goes HIGH for a certain amount of time after or during the transmission, but you might be able to find that on a datasheet.

> where does the 29.1 come from?

That's the speed of sound through air... you can use that to convert the time to centimeters. You'll have to divide it by two because it goes two ways.

Recap:

1. Arduino sends pulse to SR04 (1000 microseconds):
    `digitalWrite(trigPin,HIGH);`, `delayMicroseconds(1000);`, &`digitalWrite(trigPin,LOW);`.
2. SR04 emits a ping and changes the signal pin to HIGH
3. The ping hits an object, bounces back, and goes back to the SR04
4. The SR04 sets the pin back to LOW

The Arduino measures the length the signal pin is HIGH with this:

```
duration = pulseIn (echoPin,HIGH);
```